# Angular - unable to get selected ng-repeated radio button using ng-submit

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat

I might be missing something really simple here - but if I use ng-repeat to create a bunch of radio buttons - I cannot get the selected one using ng-submit.

The controller simply attaches an array of options to the scope.

The markup simply creates a bunch of radio buttons with ng-repeat within a form. It uses ng-submit to capture the submit event. Click 'Run code snippet' below to see the issue.

```js
 angular.module('myApp', [])
    .controller('myController', ['$scope', function($scope) {

      $scope.selectedoption = "";
      $scope.submitCalled = "";

      $scope.options=[];
      $scope.options[0]={id: "option1", name: "option 1"}
      $scope.options[1]={id: "option2", name: "option 2"}
      $scope.options[2]={id: "option3", name: "option 3"}
      $scope.options[3]={id: "option4", name: "option 4"}

      $scope.submitForm = function() {       
        console.log($scope.selectedoption);              
        $scope.submitCalled = "submit called " + $scope.selectedoption;
      };
    }]);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="myApp">

<form ng-submit="submitForm()" ng-controller="myController">    
    <div ng-repeat="option in options">
      <input type="radio" name="option" ng-value="option.id" ng-model="selectedoption">
      <label for="radio">{{option.name}}</label>
    </div>     

    <h2>{{selectedoption}}</h2>
    <h2>{{submitCalled}}</h2>

    <input type="submit" id="submit" value="Submit" />  
</form>
</div>
```

Comment: check this out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16970248/angularjs-binding-radio-buttons-to-models-with-boolean-values

Comment: ok thanks @DmitriAlgazin - but pankajparkar has the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You `ng-repeat` div should be using `ng-model="$parent.selectedoption"`

**Reason**

`ng-repeat` creates a new child scope every time, as you are declaring new `ng-model` inside ng-repeat will be added into the ng-repeat scope(child), this child scope has been created on each iteration by `ng-repeat`. As you want to create a scope variable to the parent scope, so you need to use `$parent` variable that will point the parent scope.

```
<div ng-repeat="option in options">
  <input type="radio" name="option" ng-value="option.id" ng-model="$parent.selectedoption">
  <label for="radio">{{option.name}}</label>
</div>
```

[**Demo Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/4hkw8h43/3/)

**Update**

Other good way to avoid this sort of `$parent` annotation is by using object annotation, that will do follow the [**scope prototypal inheritance**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14049480/what-are-the-nuances-of-scope-prototypal-prototypical-inheritance-in-angularjs). Only thing you need to do is define one scope variable in your controller like `$scope.selected = { option: '' }` then while using it on html you could refer it as `selected.option` directly no need to use `$parent` for parent scope reference.

[**Demo Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/4hkw8h43/5/)

Comment: @Donal yes,,I'm updating my answer

Comment: ok, thanks - unfortunately I can only upvote once - but I am sure others will.

Comment: ok, thanks. I have updated the fiddle with the second one here: https://jsfiddle.net/4hkw8h43/5/

Comment: @Donal Thanks for 2nd fiddle..I didn't get time to do it.. Happy Coding :)