# Angular and Bootstrap radio buttons conflict When Editing Form

Tags: angularjs

I am unable to get automatic radio button checked when I edit the User From using following Html and AngularJs Code. When I console  `{{changeUser}}` this returns following data

`{"id":1,"username":"Ramesh","password":"Ramesh1@23","role":"admin","active":"no"}`. When I load the edit form I have to automatically checked the `no` radio button in the following code.

```
      <div class="portlet-body form">
            <!-- BEGIN FORM-->
            <form class="form-horizontal form-bordered" name="editUserForm" data-ng-submit="userEdit(changeUser)">
                <div class="form-body">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="control-label col-md-3">Username*</label>
                        <div class="col-md-4">
                            <input class="form-control" type="text" name="userName" data-ng-model="changeUser.username"  value="{{ changeUser.username }}" data-ng-pattern="/^[a-z0-9_ .-]{5,15}$/i" required  />
                            <span style="color:red" class="error" data-ng-show="editUserForm.userName.$error.pattern" >Only letters, integers, and underscores.Minimum 5 characters to maximum 15 characters.</span>
                            <span class="help-block"></span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="control-label col-md-3">Password*</label>
                        <div class="col-md-4">
                            <input class="form-control"  type="password" name="changePassword" data-ng-model="changeUser.password" value="{{  changeUser.password}}" data-ng-pattern="usersPattern.password" required />
                            <span style="color:red" class="error" data-ng-show="editUserForm.changePassword.$error.pattern">Minimum of 8 characters, 1 capital letter,1 lowercase, 1 special-case and 1 numeric.</span>
                            <span class="help-block"></span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="control-label col-md-3">Action</label>
                        <div class="col-md-4">
                            <div class="radio-list">
                                <label class="radio-inline">
                                    <input type="radio" name="optionsRadios2"  data-ng-model="changeUser.active"  value="yes"/>
                                    Yes
                                </label>
                                <label class="radio-inline">
                                    <input type="radio" name="optionsRadios2" data-ng-model="changerUser.active" value="no"/>
                                    No
                                </label>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                    </div>
                    <div class="form-actions">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-offset-3 col-md-9">
                                <button type="submit" class="btn purple" data-ng-disabled= "editUserForm.$invalid">
                                    <i class="fa fa-check"></i> Edit</button>
                                <button type="button" class="btn red" data-ng-click="cancelEdit()">Cancel</button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

            </form>
            <!-- END FORM-->
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The Controller is

```
   (function (){

"use strict";

function UsersEditController($scope, UserFactory, $http, $location) {
    $scope.$on('$viewContentLoaded', function () {
        App.initAjax(); // initialize core components

    });
    $scope.changeUser = {};
    $scope.changeUser =  UserFactory.get();
    $scope.userEdit =  function(data) {
      $scope.changeUser = data;
        console.log($scope.changeUser);

    };

    $scope.usersPattern = {
        password: '((?=.*\\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[!@#$%]).{8,20})'

    };
    $scope.cancelEdit = function() {
        $location.path('users');
    };


}

UsersEditController.$inject = ['$scope', 'UserFactory', '$http', '$location'];

  angular.module('books').controller('UsersEditController', UsersEditController);

     })()
```

Comment: add also the JS code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

And I guess this is your answer (even without js code provided :) )

https://stackoverflow.com/a/18446612/552194

You need to add `ng-value` and use it instead of the standard `value`

Comment: I change to ng-value, but still not checked the radio button, but correct value returns when I did console.

Comment: I think you need both `ng-value` and `ng-model`

Comment: In above code, i have both ng-model and ng-value but not shown the checked button.

Comment: No, in the above code you have only `ng-model` --- `<label class="radio-inline">
                                    <input type="radio" name="optionsRadios2" data-ng-model="changerUser.active" value="no"/>
                                    No
                                </label>`

Comment: I add after some time and try this `<label class="radio-inline">
                                        <input type="radio" name="optionsRadios2"  data-ng-model="changeUser.active"  data-ng-value="yes"/>
                                        Yes
                                    </label>` but didnot work for this time also @David

Comment: hmmm. I don't know. As a workaround I suggest that you use `<select>` or `<input type="checkbox">`

Comment: When i console the object and try to edit the radio button than `active=undefined` and not showing checked on either button according to data provided.

Comment: Try this workaround: use <select> or <input type="checkbox">